# angular ui grid exception : build cannot find module '@angular/core'. How to resolve?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, angular-ui-grid

I am using **angular 1.5.0** . I installed **angular-ui-grid** through Bower. This adds multiple files and folders to the ui-router folder. If I try to build the solution this throws multiple errors in .ts files : **Build cannot find module '@angular/core'**. How am I suppose to solve this problem? 
Well I am using asp.net core for my server side development.
I even tried remoiving the added files to ui-grid. But then, it automatically adds those files again.

[image]

Comment: module '@angular/core' belongs to Angular2 and not angularJS.

Comment: I know that ... but why it shows such errors and add dependencies when I am just using ui-grid for angular 1.

Comment: I could think of couple of reasons - 1. You will be using other third party reference which is dependent in Angular2 modules OR 2. You are using older version of ASP.NET core project template where 'compile typescript on build' is by default checked.